# Type of object from udp buffer in python using metaclasses/reflection

Tags: python, sockets, udp

Is it possible to extract type of object or class name from message received on a udp socket in python using metaclasses/reflection ?

The scenario is like this:

1. Receive udp buffer on a socket.
2. The UDP buffer is a serialized binary string(a message). But the type of message is not known at this time. So can't de-serialize into appropriate message.

   Now, my ques is Can I know the classname of the seraialized binary string(recvd as UDP buffer) so that I can de-serialize into appropriate message and process further.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: As you see from your wildly differing answers, your question weren't very clear. It's usually better to be concrete and explain what they problem is.

Answer (score 2):

What you receive from the udp socket is a byte string -- that's all the "type of object or class name" that's actually *there*.  If the byte string was built as a serialized object (e.g. via `pickle`, or maybe `marshal` etc) then you can deserialize it back to an object (using e.g. `pickle.loads`) and **then** introspect to your heart's content. But most byte strings were built otherwise and will raise exceptions when you try to `loads` from them;-).

**Edit**: the OP's edit mentions the string is "a serialized object" but still doesn't say what serialization approach produced it, and that makes all the difference. `pickle` (and for a much narrower range of type `marshal`) place enough information on the strings they produce (via the `.dumps` functions of the modules) that their respective `loads` functions can deserialize back to the appropriate type; but other approaches (e.g., `struct.pack`) do not place such metadata in the strings they produce, so it's not feasible to deserialize without other, "out of bands" so to speak, indications about the format in use. So, o O.P., *how* was that serialized string of bytes produced in the first place...?

Answer (score 0):

Updated answer after updated question:

"But the type of message is not known at this time. So can't de-serialize into appropriate message."

What you get is a sequence of bytes. How that sequence of types should be interpreted is a question of how the protocol looks. Only you know what protocol you use. So if you don't know the type of message, then there is nothing you can do about it. If you are to receive a stream of data an interpret it, you must know what that data means, otherwise you can't interpret it.

It's as simple as that.

"Now, my ques is Can I know the classname of the seraialized binary string"

Yes. The classname is "str", as all strings. (Unless you use Python 3, in which case you would not get a str but a binary). The data inside that str has no classname. It's just binary data. It means whatever the sender wants it to mean.

Again, I need to stress that you should not try to make this into a generic question. Explain exactly what you are trying to do, not generically, but specifically.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a serialization module.  [pickle](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html) and [marshal](http://docs.python.org/library/marshal.html) are both options.  They provide functions to turn objects into bytestreams, and back again.